# Allowing remote access in MySql 8.0 not allowed

Tags: mysql

A lot of the existing answers are targeting the old MySQL and I haven't been able to find a solution for the new MySQL 8.0.

```
mysql> SELECT user FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+
| user             |
+------------------+
| mysql.infoschema |
| mysql.session    |
| mysql.sys        |
| r00t             |
| root             |
+------------------+
```

I have already a user called r00t.

When I login as `root` and try to give `r00t` remote permission:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO r00t@'18.132.x.xxx';
```

> ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT

But the user already exists, so what gives?

The old way doesn't work either:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'r00t'@'18.132.x.xxx' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'myPass';
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY
>   'myPass'' at line 1

Comment: you must separate `CREATE USER` and `GRANT` in MYSQL-8.0.

Comment: The host is part of "the user". Check your user table if your host-information matches.

Comment: Are you really using `x.xxx` to indicate a range or is that really a specific ip address you just dont want to show

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's a specific IP address, i don't want to show.

Comment: @danblack But I'm not creating a user, right? I want to give permissions to an existing user.

Comment: see host is part of the `user`. `SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user` and use the same `host` part for your `GRANT`. "old way" is definitely dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MYSQL the users account is identified by the username and the domain i.e.

```
username        domain
`r00t`    and   '18.132.x.xxx'
```

So if you created a `'r00t'@'localhost'` it is not the same as `'r00t'@'18.132.x.xxx'`

So in fact you are trying to create a new account, or rather `'r00t'@'18.132.x.xxx'` does not exist yet, hence the error.

So first you should create the account `'r00t'@'18.132.x.xxx'`